# public list of world banks - comprehensive - especially small banks are interesting

Tags: data, bank

i am looking for a public list of world banks

I don't need branch offices and full addresses - but the name and the website.
I think of data ... XML, CSV ... with these fields :

bank name,
country name or country code (ISO two letters)
website:
optional : city of bank headquarters
For each bank, one record per country of presence.

btw: especially small banks are interesting